# Can not run app on Android emulator : error message kvm is required to run AVD

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my app on Android emulator but it shows me the below error :

[image]
I use Ubuntu as OS .

**Edited**

I tried to open the bios to enable virtualization by shut down and open the computer and keep tapping F2 and F12 keys but in vain . Bios is not opened .

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.

Comment: Yeah it seems that this is the problem as you said . However, I tried to open the bios by shuting down and opening the computer and keep tapping  F2 and F12 keys but in vain . Bios is not opened :/

Comment: google for the instructions specific for your device model, on how to open BIOS settings? Maybe the key combination is different for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- sudo apt install cpu-checker
- In VMware, go setting->Processors->Virtualization Engine, check
  "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI.
- sudo kvm-ok

Comment: I don't have VMware. I tried to create Android emulator via Android studio